# How to add Azure storage library to Android project in Android Studio

Tags: maven, azure, android-studio, sdk

I want to add this library to my project: https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java

They have 3 options but they are not well explained.How can i add this library to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution myself.To install library press ctrl+shift+alt+s then click "app" under modules at left column.Then click "Dependencies",Then click "+" sign and library dependency.Write library name you want to download.Click "ok"That is all.